# Embedding and homeomorphism

Tags: general-topology

Suppose there exists an embedding from one topological space into another, and conversely. Is it always true that there is a homeomorphism between the two spaces?

Comment: Hint:  Consider intervals:

Answer (score 3):

Embeddings have an easy answer: $(0,1)$ embeds into $[0,1]$ by inclusion, and reversely too, using $f(x) = \frac{1}{3}x + \frac{1}{3}$, e.g.

But you can even have two continuous bijections between spaces: see [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/q/30661/2060) and its many answers.