# Does $(0,1)$ embed in $[0,1]$ through inclusion or identity?

Tags: general-topology

Given two spaces $X,Y$, we say that $X$ is embedded in $Y$ if there is a homeomorphism $f: X \to A \subseteq Y$

My question is let $X = (0,1)$, and $Y = [0,1]$, does $X$ embed in $Y$ by inclusion map or identity map?

In this [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1834090/embedding-and-homeomorphism), it says $X$ is embedded in $Y$ through inclusion

My question why not through the identity map?

Comment: You can use the inclusion because you don't have an image of $0$ or $1$ in $X$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $X$ is a set, the identity map $\mathrm{id}_X\colon X\to X$ is defined by $\mathrm{id}_X(x) = x$. Note that the domain and codomain of $\mathrm{id}_X$ are both $X$.

If $X$ is a subset of $Y$, the inclusion map $i\colon X\to Y$ is defined by $i(x) = x$. So $i$ is defined by the same formula as $\mathrm{id}_X$, but the codomain is allowed to be different.

We might say that $i$ is the *identity on elements of $X$* (since it carries an element $x$ of $X$ to itself), but we shouldn't say that $i$ is the *identity map*. Every identity map is an inclusion (since $X\subseteq X$), but not every inclusion is an identity map.

---

**Edit:** Oh, after reading your comment below I've realized that I misunderstood your question. Whenever you have a function $f\colon X\to Y$, you also have a function $f'\colon X\to \mathrm{im}(X)\subseteq Y$. These functions do the same thing to elements, but they have different codomains: the codomain of $f$ is $Y$, while the codomain of $f'$ is $\text{im}(f)$.

Now the usual definition of embedding says that $f\colon X\to Y$ is an embedding if and only if $f'$ is a homeomorphism. That is, $X$ is homeomorphic to its image in $Y$ under $f$. The definition given in your question is a little unusual, because it highlights the function $f'$ instead of $f$, and it defines what it means for $X$ to *be embedded* in $Y$ without saying what an *embedding* is.

In the case $X = (0,1)$ and $Y = [0,1]$, the map $f$ is the inclusion $(0,1)\to [0,1]$, the image of $f$ is again $(0,1)$, and $f'$ is the identity map $(0,1)\to (0,1)$. It's $f$ (the inclusion map) which is the embedding of $X$ into $Y$, not $f'$ (the identity map). The fact that $f$ is an embedding is witnessed by the fact that $f'$ is a homeomorphism.

Comment: When do we use the hooked arrow for inclusion map?

Comment: I don't think there's a standard convention about usage of the hooked arrow. Sometimes it's used for any injective map and sometimes only for inclusions. Typically, it's used to emphasize that a map is injective or an inclusion... people often write down injective maps or inclusion maps without using a hooked arrow.

Comment: Note that in set theory, depending on the definitions, a function may not have a built in domain and codomain, so that the identity and inclusion maps are set-wise identical. Thus in such a context you can get away with saying "the identity map is an inclusion from $(0,1)$ to $[0,1]$".

Comment: But an inclusion map is not surjective, since $1 \in [0,1]$ does not have a corresponding element in the preimage, aren't we looking for a homeomorphism

Comment: @MSE An inclusion map is not *necessarily* surjective; in fact it is surjective iff it is an identity map.

Comment: @MSE Re: homeomorphism, what you are looking for is a homeomorphism from $X$, to $Y$ restricted to the range of $f$ ($=A$). In this case $X=A=(0,1)$ and $Y=[0,1]$, so the identity map on $(0,1)$ is indeed a homeomorphism from $X$ to $A$ and so it is an embedding from $X$ to $Y$.

Answer (score 1):

A function $f:A\to B$ consists of three "ingredients": A domain $A$, a codomain $B$, and a relation $R_f\subseteq A\times B$ satisfying the following properties:

1. For each $a\in A$, there exists $b\in B$ with $(a,b)\in R_f$;
2. For each $a\in A$ and $b,c\in B$, if $(a,b)\in R_f$ and $(a,c)\in R_f$, then $b=c$.

We usually identify the function with $R_f$, and write $f(a)$ for the unique element of $B$ for which $(a,f(a))\in R_f$. From $R_f$ we can obtain $A$ back, namely, $A=\left\{a:\exists b, (a,b)\in R_f\right\}$<sup>(1)</sup>. However, it is not possible to obtain $B$ back from $R_f$, but only the *image* of $f$. So we always need to specify the codomain of $f$.

All that said, in general the (an) *identity* map on a set $X$ consists of the function $i_X:X\to X$ with $i_X(x)=x$ for all $x\in X$, while an *inclusion* map is a map of the form $f:X\to Y$, where $Y\supseteq X$, and $f(x)=x$ for all $x\in X$. But again, this is mostly semantics and should not cause problems.

---

<sub>(1) I'm abusing notation a little bit, because I'm not specifying the domain of variables, but let's think we are working on some large set.</sub>